# How to validate login in android app using web API

Tags: java, android, json, validation, authentication

I am trying to make an Android Application where the login credentials have to verified using a web API which is fetching details from SQL Server Database. The way how I have to validate the login is that when the user enters "username" and "password" then onClick of "login" button an HTTP request in the form of `myURL/username/password/1` is hit, which checks for the validation and returns a JSON response like `{"data1":0,"data2":"ok","data3":{"data4": [{"data5":2,"data6":"somedata","data7":"somedata","data8":"someNumber","data9":"","data10":"somedata","data11":somedata}]}}`

Now here, I am interested in "data2". If the response from data2 is "ok" it means the credentials are correct, while the response "Invalid Login" means incorrect credentials. What is the correct way to fetch the response from `data2`?

Here is what I tried so far -

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    password=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);  
    userName=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);  
    login=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);  
    //on click of login button
    login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  
            String s1=userName.getText().toString();  
            String s2=password.getText().toString();  
            new ExecuteTask().execute(s1,s2);
        }
    });
}

class ExecuteTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>  
{  
    @Override  
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {  

        String res=PostData(params);  

        return res;  
    }

    @Override  
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {  
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);  
    //progess_msz.setVisibility(View.GONE);  
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, 3000).show();  
    }

}

public String PostData(String[] valuse) {
    String s="";  
    try  
    {
        HttpClient httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();  
        HttpPost httpPost=new HttpPost("myURL" + userName + "/" + passWord + "/1");
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(list));  
        HttpResponse httpResponse=  httpClient.execute(httpPost);  

        HttpEntity httpEntity=httpResponse.getEntity();  
        s= readResponse(httpResponse);
    }
    catch(Exception exception)  {}  
    return s;  
}

public String readResponse(HttpResponse res) {  
    InputStream is=null;   
    String return_text="";  
    try
    {  
        is=res.getEntity().getContent();  
        BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));  
        String line="";  
        StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();  
        while ((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)  
        {
            sb.append(line);  
        }  
        return_text=sb.toString();  
    } catch (Exception e)  
    {  

    }  
    return return_text;
}
```

Is there any better/updated way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: Hi Aman, you should use volley or Retrofit for the network calls. that would be easier for you to hit API's call and play with responses

Comment: @HappySingh can either of these parse the data that I am getting in the form of JSON response?